# Zapier application: send body with GET request

Tags: node.js, https, zapier, zapier-cli

I'm making an integration for the [intouch api](https://help.intouch.cloud/article/c2r366oa2k-api) in Zapier. For some reason, the API is set up to receive queries in the `body` of the `GET` requests, rather than in the parameters.

This is all working in Postman but it seems that the `z.request` function ignores a `body` option attribute with `GET` requests.

Here is my code:

```
const test = (z, bundle) => {
  const query = {
    matterGuid: "bf508fcf-5f36-4191-93d6-fecd5a7f6a04",
    getFields: ["matter.reference"],
  };

  return z.request({
    method: "GET",
    url: baseUrl + "/matters",
    body: JSON.stringify(query), //I've tried body, json, raw, data, etc
  });
};
```

And here is the response I receive:

```
{
      status: 400,
      json: { message: 'No request data received', success: false, errors: [] },
      data: { message: 'No request data received', success: false, errors: [] },
      content: '{"message":"No request data received","success":false,"errors":[]}',
      request: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'user-agent': 'Zapier',
          'x-intouch-o-token': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        },
        url: 'https://demo.intouch.cloud/api/v2/public/matters',
        _addContext: [Function: addContext],
        input: {
          bundle: [Object],
          _zapier: [Object],
          _addContext: [Function: addContext]
        },
        merge: true,
        removeMissingValuesFrom: { params: false, body: false },
        replace: true,
        skipThrowForStatus: false,
        _requestStart: 2020-10-24T11:42:37.026Z
      },
      skipThrowForStatus: false,
      headers: Headers {
        [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] {
          date: [Array],
          'content-type': [Array],
          'content-length': [Array],
          connection: [Array],
          'set-cookie': [Array],
          'access-control-allow-origin': [Array],
          'access-control-allow-headers': [Array],
          'access-control-allow-methods': [Array],
          'x-content-type-options': [Array],
          'arr-disable-session-affinity': [Array],
          'x-frame-options': [Array],
          'strict-transport-security': [Array],
          'cf-cache-status': [Array],
          'cf-request-id': [Array],
          'expect-ct': [Array],
          'report-to': [Array],
          nel: [Array],
          server: [Array],
          'cf-ray': [Array]
        }
      },
      getHeader: [Function: getHeader],
      throwForStatus: [Function],
      _addContext: [Function: addContext]
    }
```

Comment: Looking into this, I've found out why this is happening. It's due to this line in the Zapier requests code:


`// No need for body on get`
  `if (req.method === 'GET') {`
    `delete req.body;`
`  }`


https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-core/blob/master/src/http-middlewares/before/prepare-request.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is not the ideal solution but I've found a workaround for this.

[I discovered that as part of the middleware](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-core/blob/master/src/http-middlewares/before/prepare-request.js) in the `z.request` method, the `body` is explicitly deleted from `GET` requests.

```
// No need for body on get
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    delete req.body;
  }
```

As a result, I was able to add in more middleware to put the body back in. Fortunately, the custom middleware functions added to the `before` array run after Zapier's own middleware, meaning that the body was not affected by the function above.

This is what I came up with to get around this:

```
const includeQuery = (request, z, bundle) => {
  if (request.method ==='GET'){
    if (bundle.inputData.matterGuid && bundle.inputData.getFields){
      const query = {
        matterGuid: bundle.inputData.matterGuid,
        getFields: bundle.inputData.getFields.split(','),
      };
      request.body = JSON.stringify(query);
    }    
  }

  return request;
};
```

This was then added to the `befores` array in the exported object, like this:

```
  befores: [includeApiKey, includeQuery],
  afters: [handleBadResponses],
```

I'd be really interested to hear if anyone has a better solution to this issue.

Comment: Yours is the correct solution - per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body), the body of a `GET` request shouldn't hold data and should be ignored by the server, so Zapier removes it.